# is checking $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] to determine request type bad practice?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I'm making a system that needs to be able to accept input from both get and post and process accordingly. I want to avoid $_REQUEST because some of our servers aren't configured to use it and I don't want to micromanage that. What I'd like to know is if it's bad practice to do something like this:

```
    switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        case 'POST':
            $this->_process($_POST); 
            break;
        case 'GET': 
            $this->_process($_GET);
            break;
    }
```

*Ignore the lack of preprocessing of post data for now

Comment: why not check $_POST and  $_GET directly?

Comment: this is not bad practice

Comment: I wouldn't recommend passing $_* as a function argument, may contain heaven and hell. Secure it asap and go from there.

Comment: I'm not saying this is bad, just offering an alternative. In CodeIgniter you COULD also check `if ($this->input->post())` which will return true if there is any post-data

Comment: user247245: I said ignore the lack of preprocessing ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the method of the request is exactly what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is intended for. So no problem with that.

This value is actually part of the [CGI specification](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html) and should therefore be provided by any decent webserver:

> The REQUEST_METHOD meta-variable MUST be set to the method which
>      should be used by the script to process the request, as described in
>      section 4.3.